# How to pass oauth_callback value to oauth/request_token with Twython

Tags: python, django, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

Twitter just recently made the following mandatory:

1) You must pass an `oauth_callback` value to oauth/request_token. It's not optional. Even if you have one already set on dev.twitter.com. If you're doing out of band OAuth, pass `oauth_callback=oob`.

2) You must pass along the `oauth_verifier` you either received from your executed callback or that you received hand-typed by your end user to oauth/access_token.
Here is the twitter thread (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16443)

This has caused Twython `get_authorized_tokens` to throw this error:

```
Request: oauth/access_token

Error: Required oauth_verifier parameter not provided
```

I have two questions:

**1. How do you pass the `oauth_callback` value to oauth/request_token with Twython?**

**2. How do you pass along the `oauth_verifier`?**

I can get the `oauth_verifier` with request.GET['oauth_verifier'] from the callback url but I have no idea what to do from there using Twython. I've search everywhere but haven't found any answers so I decided to post this. This is my first post so please be kind ;)

Here is my code:

```
def register_twitter(request):
    # Instantiate Twython with the first leg of our trip.
    twitter = Twython(
        twitter_token = settings.TWITTER_KEY,
        twitter_secret = settings.TWITTER_SECRET,
        callback_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('account.views.twitter_thanks'))
    )

    # Request an authorization url to send the user to
    auth_props = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()

    # Then send them over there
    request.session['request_token'] = auth_props
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_props['auth_url'])


def twitter_thanks(request, redirect_url=settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL):

    # Now that we've got the magic tokens back from Twitter, we need to exchange
    # for permanent ones and store them...
    twitter = Twython(
        twitter_token = settings.TWITTER_KEY,
        twitter_secret = settings.TWITTER_SECRET,
        oauth_token = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token'],
        oauth_token_secret = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token_secret'],
    )

    # Retrieve the tokens
    authorized_tokens = twitter.get_authorized_tokens()

    # Check if twitter user has a UserProfile
    try:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(twitter_username=authorized_tokens['screen_name'])
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        profile = None
```

Comment: your `reverse('account.views.twitter_thanks')` is incorrect, it must be `reverse('account:twitter_thanks')`. Can you post you url codes

Comment: @catherine Actually `reverse('account.views.twitter_thanks')` works fine. Here is the url: `url(r'^register/twitter/thanks/?$', 'account.views.twitter_thanks', name='twitter_thanks')`. It's nice to know a shorthand way of writing the view though, thanks for that.

Comment: Where did you get these codes? Actually, your codes are the same with my twitter login and it's perfectly working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own answer. Here is the solution if it can help anyone else:

In the file Twython.py, I added a new parameter `oauth_verifier` to the Twython class constructor . I get the `oauth_verifier` value from the `callback_url` in my twitter_thanks view.

In `get_authorized_tokens` I removed this line of code:

```
response = self.client.get(self.access_token_url)
```

and added the following code:

```
callback_url = self.callback_url or 'oob'
request_args = urllib.urlencode({'oauth_callback': callback_url, 'oauth_verifier':self.oauth_verifier })
response = self.client.post(self.access_token_url, params=request_args)
```

It now works like a charm and is OAuth 1.0A compliant.