# Using Twython to send a tweet, twitter api error

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, twython

I'm trying to make python send a tweet for me using [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/) but for some reason everything I'm trying isn't working.

I've followed the [Twython README](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/README.rst) but still unable to acheive what I want.

Below is my latest attempted code:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

APP_KEY = "KEYHERE"
APP_SECRET = "SECRETHERE"

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()

OAUTH_TOKEN = auth['oauth_token']
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = auth['oauth_token_secret']

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

try:
    twitter.update_status(status='See how easy this was?')
except TwythonError as e:
    print e
```

On running the above code I get the following traceback error:

```
Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid or expired token
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and more importantly how do I fix this?

I dont have enough points for a bounty, but I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance

**edit**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testtweet.py", line 20, in <module>
    final_step = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(oauth_verifier)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\api.py", line 313, in get_authorized_tokens
    raise TwythonError('Unable to decode authorized tokens.')
TwythonError: Unable to decode authorized tokens.
```

The above is the traceback recieved from the code supplied by @justhalf

Thanks SMNALLY

Comment: Answered the question. Solution completely works :)

Comment: the reason why the code is returning `Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid or expired token` is it needs `'oauth_verifier'` after `get_authentication_tokens()` more on it [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) also [this might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17308270/2541442)

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15857542/2541442) to get `oauth_verifier`

Comment: Thanks Simon I will check it out.

Comment: @SMNALLY Was I able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a far simpler way to update your post as opposed to the way `Twython` *actually* shows you. It will take more work on your API console space though, so let me begin.

1. Firstly, you will need to go to your [apps page](https://dev.twitter.com/apps). After you've selected the application that you are using right now, take a look at the page you are given. You should be at the **Details** tab by default.
                  [image]
2. Now that you are where you're supposed to be, click on the **Settings** tab right next to the **Details** tab as shown above.
3. After that, scroll down until you see this:
   [image]
4. Click the option as shown above. Now after you've selected the option scroll down until you see a blue button saying **Update this twitter's application settings**.
5. Now, head back over to your **Details** tab. Go to the bottom and generate your required tokens, please note that you might have to click the buttons a couple of times to get it to work (also, make sure that your access level is *Read, write, and direct messages* when the token is generated):
   [image]
6. Now you have everything necessary for connecting and posting to your twitter account. You have the `Consumer key` and the `Consumer Secret`, the `Access token` and the `Access token secret`. You have everything that you need.

Okay, now head over to your code editor, and write the following boiler-plate code (these keys wont work, I just got rid of the application, so no hacking here :P I've given them simply as an indication of the length of the keys that you should expect):

```
from twython import Twython

APP_KEY = ''  # Customer Key here
APP_SECRET = ''  # Customer secret here
OAUTH_TOKEN = '1936951807-z5bBNING8P1TU2onWvJh5dh8hoYlYAmNOaAx2OX'  # Access Token here
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'QWJEZ7ridSeZGdxJELSBk7mupCpMA9q9sLCou5ywg'  # Access Token Secret here

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

twitter.update_status(status="Hello from Python! :D")
```

After this, check your twitter, you should see a new tweet saying "Hello from Python! :D".

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please say something. Because I was helping a friend with this problem. I gave him the same solution.

Comment: yeap, this works well, up vote for mentioning the settings part on  apps page of twitter, also I want to add make sure the box         `Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter` is **unchecked**

Comment: @SimonKB You don't really need that to be turned on. It was turned off for me, and I was able to post my message on twitter. I don't think it matters on client side.

Comment: hmm, sorry about it, it seems to be working fine with it checked as well, my bad.

Comment: Perfect answer :)  Works perfectly :)

Comment: So I'm doing this, but it gives me a 401 can't authenticate error when trying to upload media files likes images. Any ideas about how to deal with that?

Comment: +1 I happened to try to make my cli work following through Twitter documentation. All things failed, but need enable `Read, Write and Direct message` as per your suggestion so I can finally update tweet via REST API. Horrible documentation :( Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to find out together what went wrong.

I notice this in the [documentation](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/README.rst):

> Now that you have the `oauth_verifier` stored to a variable, you'll want to create a new instance of Twython and grab the final user tokens

And the code below it:

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,
              OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

final_step = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(oauth_verifier)
```

So it seems that you missed the `final_step`?

Then after that (from documentation):

> Once you have the final user tokens, store them in a database for later use!:

```
OAUTH_TOKEN = final_step['oauth_token']
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECERT = final_step['oauth_token_secret']
```

After that I guess you will need to create another new Twython instance with the final `OAUTH_TOKEN` and `OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET`. So the complete code would be something like this, I presume:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import requests

APP_KEY = "KEYHERE"
APP_SECRET = "SECRETHERE"

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()

OAUTH_TOKEN = auth['oauth_token']
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = auth['oauth_token_secret']

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

### This is the part you're missing ###
oauth_verifier_url = auth['auth_url']
oauth_verifier = requests.get(oauth_verifier_url)

# Getting the FINAL authentication tokens
final_step = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(oauth_verifier)

OAUTH_TOKEN = final_step['oauth_token']
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = auth['oauth_token_secret']

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
### Up until this line ###

try:
    twitter.update_status(status='See how easy this was?')
except TwythonError as e:
    print e
```

I don't have Twitter app key, so I can't try it.

But I guess this should be enough to resolve your problem. I hope this helps. =)

Note that I used the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package from Python.

Comment: Hi @justhalf thanks for your reply, In your first line where you define `twitter` you can't have `OAUTH_TOKEN` and `OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET` because you haven't been able to get the tokens, the part what is supposed to get tokens is `auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()` If I `print auth` I get the token numbers and everything needed but it seems to expire straight away, also where do I define what account(s) to login/post with? Any thoughts? Many thanks SMNALLY

Comment: The first code in my sample is not the first line, I copied it from the documentation. It is supposed to be put after your first `twitter` definition. See the update on my answer.

Comment: sorry, not your first `twitter` definition, but the second.

Comment: I attempted to do this the same way, but the API has changed a little.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why the code is returning `Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid or expired token` is it needs **oauth_verifier** after a call to `get_authentication_tokens()`
Try thsse steps for a successful call to twitter & get the `oauth_verifier`

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)

auth = twitter.get_authorization_tokens(callback_url='http://google.com')
oauth_token = auth['oauth_token']
oauth_token_secret = auth['oauth_token_secret']
print auth
print auth['auth_url']
```

**auth['auth_url']** will print a response something like:

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxx

browse to this URL to authorize your app

[image]

After the app gets authorize, it will send the client to your `callback_url`

The `callback_url` will be appended with the `oauth_verifier`

something like `http://google.com/?oauth_verifier=xxxxxx&oauth_token=xxxxxx`

depending on the webframework you are using you need to **GET** the response for `oauth_verifier`
Now  create a new Twython instance

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
final_tokens = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(oauth_verifier)

print final_tokens

# these are the keys you will use to make calls on the users behalf from here on forward
f_oauth_token = final_tokens['oauth_token']
f_oauth_token_secret = final_tokens['oauth_token_secret']
```

**Updating Twitter Status:**

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN=f_oauth_token, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET=f_oauth_token_secret)

try:
    twitter.update_status(status='See how easy this was?')
except TwythonError as e:
    print e
```

And do **Update twitter's application settings** as mentioned by @Games Brainiac

Answer (score 0):

I am adding to the following discussion that a connection to another server might also prevent the connection on the stream api. For example, I had a Rserve() open and kept getting the 401 error but when I killall Rserve in my command prompt , the authorization was granted...

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to update a status using your app, you have to be authenticated using the OAuth1.1 authentication (which is being referred to as a User Authentication - as opposed to Application-only Authentication).

Unfortunately for anyone creating a Twitter app, this requires a lot of additional code (where app auth only requires like 3 or 4 lines of code).

Some time ago I have actually posted a full code for dealing with OAuth1.1 using Flask and Twython (without error handling, you could deal with this any way you wish) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870722/twitter-user-authentication-oauth-1-1-with-twython-and-flask). This solution is using session files to handle tokens, and then clears session on logout. (the code might not be perfect and could probably be improved - I am a rather novice programmer)