# Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), An error occurred processing your request

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

Here's my code for getting the followers and updating a status:

```
from twython import Twython,TwythonError
APP_KEY='mykey'
APP_SECRET='mysecret'
OAUTH_TOKEN='mytoken'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET='mytokensecret'
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
followers = twitter.get_followers_ids(screen_name = "darcythegreat")

for follower_id in followers:
    print follower_id

try:
    twitter.update_status(status='My first status using Twython')
except TwythonError as e:
    print e
```

And here's the [LINK](https://twitter.com/DarcyTheGreat) to my Twitter.

After running it I receive the following error:

```
python tweet.py 
previous_cursor
previous_cursor_str
next_cursor
ids
next_cursor_str
Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), An error occurred processing your request.
```

Can you please let me know which steps I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This StackOverflow answer worked for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196583/768671)**
    I had to change the permissions on my account. Also, the code given here is much simpler:

Comment: I have the same exact problem: a 401 error when calling for get_followers_ids, but the linked answer seems to not work for me. I understand this is an old answer but still, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why a 401 can occur, some that aren't related to the code you've written. A common reason is a difference in clock times between your and Twitter's server. Here's a link to the Twitter OAuth FAQ: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/faq

Comment: This was indeed the case for me. my pc was set 1 hour in the future without me noticing and kept getting 401; solved by resetting the correct time.

Comment: Anyone knows what time zone is the twitter server in?

Comment: @JorgeMauricio IIRC, you can check by doing a Get on an endpoint and looking at the response header from Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Just Regenerating API,API-SECRET,ACCESS, ACCESS-TOKEN...Worked for me